# gdb: break when a variable is reset

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

I am attempting to debug a program that seems to be having issues with pointer passing.  I have a class defined as below:

```
class data{
public:
    data(int x, int y){
        a=x;
        b=y;
        md = new metadata();
    }
    ~data(){
        delete md;
    }

    int a;
    int b;

    metadata* md; //metadata is another class
};
```

and several functions that take a pointer to a data object:

```
void function1(data* d){
    //do stuff
}

void function2(data* d){
    //do stuff
    function1(d);
}

void function3(data* d){
    //do stuff
    function2(d);
}

int main(){
    //stuff
    data* data = new data(1,2);
    function3(d);
    //other stuff
}
```

I have a breakpoint set in `function1` and one in `function3`. somewhere between these two breakpoints, `md` gets reassigned to point to a different metadata object (`d`, though, still points to the same memory address).  There are thousands of lines executed between the two breakpoints, so its not really feasible to just step through, so I want to watch and break when the `md` pointer is changed.  however, `watch d->md` for the breakboint in `function1` does not work, as I get a message saying

```
Watchpoint 1 deleted because the program has left the block in which its expression is valid
```

which presumably occurs because in `d` is local to the context of the function.  Is there a way to watch the memory address in which the `md` pointer is stored to see when it gets changed (i.e. when `md` is reassigned) and break there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the address of `d->md` using `print d->md` and watch the expression `*((metadata *)0x....)` instead of using the name `d`.

Comment: I no longer get the `Watchpoint deleted` error, however now the program freezes when I try to continue.  Any idea why?

Comment: try to watch a different expression, for example the value of a member of d->md by address, e.g., get the address of d->md->some_member. Perhaps md does not change but the values are changing.

Comment: @perreal You mean `print &d->md`, not `print d->md`, and then `watch *(metadata**)0x...`. Also, this is much easier to achieve with `watch -l d->md`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thanks!  The problem was solved by using `watch *(metadata**)0x...`